# nameserver clarification

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

Basically,i a machines(vm);a window server which i use in hosting sites.i simply created ns.mydomain.com at my domain registra and simply pointed it to the IP of my window machine.Everything works fine by just pointing a new domain name to that nameserver.

**ns1.mydomain.com ==> IP of window server**

**ns2.mydomain.com ==> IP of window server**

for any domain i need to host on that server;i simply point it to that nameserver and it works fine.

I just added a second server(a linux box) and what iv simply done is to extend my initial nameserver by
**ns3.mydomain.com ==> ip of linux server**

**ns4.mydomain.com ==> ip of linux server**

I really want to know if this approach is right or do i av to setup a new nameserver on a new domain name because when i checked the "/etc/resolv.conf" file.i saw something like
mydomain.com
IP
IP

But originally,mydomain.com by itself is hosted on the window machine.

Comment: Are you running your own DNS servers on both the Windows VM and the linux box ?

Comment: yes....i use window DNS on d window vm and i use BIND for d linux vm.

Answer (score 1):

If BIND is properly configured on the Linux VM to serve those domains, and to look to the Windows VM as master, and if the Windows VM is configured to allow the Linux VM to do zone transfers, and each zonefile lists all four `NS` records, then yes, that should be all you need.

That said, there's no point listing each machine twice, so the right thing to do (once you've verified the server setup) is to **change** `ns2.mydomain.com` to point to the IP of the Linux VM.